# Open Group Link in Facebook APP NOT Browser

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I have created a simple button saying join group and it has a simple link to my facebook group. However on mobile when I click on the link, it goes to the group in the web browser rather than the actual facebook app itself.

**I want to send users from my website to my group on Facebook. I do not want the group to be opened in a browser, but in the Facebook App**

Thank you!

Tried using simple button on landing page. - Not a coder, but know how to place and use simple HTML/scripts etc.. just looking for a way to get this working.